# Many to many tables how to view on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this three tables  :

```
Table 1. users

'first_name', 'last_name', 'bio', 'image', 'email', 'password', 'user_group','remember_token',

Table 2. professions

'id', 'title',

Table 3 user_profesions
```

'id','user_id', 'profession_id'

I combined the users table with user_professions table like this:

```
    public function index(){


        $mentors = User::where('user_group', 2)->get();



    $all_professions = Profession::get();

        foreach($mentors as $mentor) {
            $mentor->professions =  UserProfession::where('user_id', $mentor->id)->get();
        } 



dd($mentors);
        return view('mentors.list-of-mentors')->with(['mentors'=>$mentors, 'all_professions' => $all_professions]); 
    }
```

So it gives me this when I die dump

[image]

I am also passing the all professions from professions table.
In view I am doing it like this

```
  @foreach($mentors as $mentor)
{{$mentor->first_name}}
    @foreach($all_professions as $profession)
                {{$profession}}
                 @endforeach

@endforeach
```

I am stuck here I don't know how to make the professions for that particular user to appear.. Can someone please help me..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use eloquent ManyToMany relationship to fetch data between `User` and `Profession` model. And for that you have to define it like this

User Model

```
public function professions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Profession','user_profesions');
}
```

Profession Model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_profesions');
}
```

Now fetch it like this in controller

```
$mentors = User::with('professions')->where('user_group', 2)->get();
return view('mentors.list-of-mentors')->with('mentors',$mentors);
```

In view you can use it like this

```
@foreach($mentors as $mentor)
      {{$mentor->first_name}}
      @foreach($mentor->professions as $profession)
           {{$profession}}
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Check here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: It gives me error to this foreach($mentor->professions as $profession  it says syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Comment: did you add relationship ?

Comment: it was ; after die and dump yu forgot

Comment: you need to remove, `dd` and the php foreach is only for example let me update

Answer (score 0):

Add relationship mathods to your models.
UserModel

```
public function professions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Profession::class);
}
```

ProfessionModel:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

And now you can do this:

```
$user = User::where('user_group', 2)->with('professions')->get();
dd($user->professions);
```